# Check into the new branch after svn copy

Tags: svn

I created a branch of my project using svn copy:

```
svn copy $svn_url/branches/prj $svn_url/branches/prj_copy -m "Creating a copy"
```

I have a local check out of `prj`. How can I check in the changes in my local `prj` folder into `$svn_url/branches/prj_copy` instead of `$svn_url/branches/prj` from now on?

I'm using svn on linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `svn switch` to change your working copy to the new branch. Use this from a command prompt within your working copy folder:

```
svn switch $svn_url/branches/prj_copy
```